# Joining SQL Server rows by same location

Tags: sql-server

I'm needing to concatenate row data so I can output as one table row on the page.

On occasion there are new items and refurbished items in the same location. This data appears on 2 rows in the database, but I need to be able to query as if one row to output the HTML.

[image]

There's a fair amount of ordering and conditions already thrown into the query, which I hope won't render this impossible!

I need to group the results by `ShopStock.Location` - I've tried `GROUP BY ShopStock.Location`, but this didn't seem to do the job.

The SQL query so far is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ShopStock
INNER JOIN ShopPricing ON ShopStock.OriginalPartNumber = ShopPricing.OriginalPartNumber
WHERE ShopStock.OriginalPartNumber = '$query[0]' 
  AND ShopPricing.CustomerID = '$id'
ORDER BY
    (CASE WHEN ShopStock.PartNumber = '$query[1]' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
    ShopStock.ItemQty DESC,
    ShopStock.PartNumber ASC,
    ShopStock.CountryCode DESC,
    (CASE WHEN ShopStock.CountryCode = 'GB' AND ShopStock.Location = 'LONDON' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
    (CASE WHEN ShopStock.CountryCode = 'FR' AND ShopStock.Location = 'PARIS' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
    ShopStock.Location ASC,
    ShopStock.Condition ASC
```

Comment: It is hard to relate your query and your data. You might want to provide more representative sample data (as tabular text), along with the results that you actually expect.

Comment: If you tried grouping, then that means you had to actually list the columns you needed in your column list - which you should be doing anyways. So show that attempt and define "didn't work" (though we can guess, it is better you make that effort). And always tag the version of sql server you are using since functionality varies.

Comment: What's the relationship between OriginalPartNumber and PartNumber and what effect does Condition have on them? Do New and Refurb parts of the same type have the same OriginalPartNumber but different PartNumber (possibly with OriginalPartNumber of refurb = PartNumber of the respective New part)? Is the price based solely on the OriginalPartNumber?